# Accessing file displayed on image control in the controller in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, file-upload

I have two images displayed on  control that I want to process in a method in the controller and return the result on the page. How do I access these images in the controller code on the click of a button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways can solve this problem.

1.Let's start with the controller. Basiclly you should find the return of the *FileContentResult*. What you need to do first is defining a function in the controller as an Action. For exapmle, I draw a picture here:

```
 Public ActionResult GetImg()
{
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(350, 500);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.Clear(Color.Bisque);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 50, 2, 100, 100);
            g.DrawString("MVC", new Font("Consolas", 15f), Brushes.Yellow, new PointF(50f, 5f));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            g.Dispose();
            bmp.Dispose();
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");}
```

After that, we add following code in the front-end:

```
 <img src="/Home/GetImg" alt="preview">
```

Now you can display the images.

2.It's just like the first one. Only a liitle difference. Here's code for the controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetImg()
{
            string strPath = @"\\ServerIP\Signature\1.png";
            Image img = Image.FromFile(strPath);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

And here's what we invoke in the front-end:

```
$("#ImageId").attr("src", "/Admin/Help/GetImg");
```